# Basic C Memory Allocation

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocateMem(int *a)
{
    a = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    allocateMem(ptr);
    ptr[0] = 5454;
    ptr[1] = 54;
    printf("Hi %d\n", ptr[1]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't get any output and error with the code. But if I allocate memory in main function, it actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void allocateMem(int **a)
{
    *a = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    allocateMem(&ptr);
    ptr[0] = 5454;
    ptr[1] = 54;
    printf("Hi %d\n", ptr[1]);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

To write to a variable in another function, you need to pass a pointer to it. Since the intention here is to write to a pointer, you need to pass the address of the pointer - `&ptr`.

As an address was passed, the `allocateMem()` function dereferences `a` once to hop into the memory location which is to be updated and lays down the address returned by `malloc()`. When this function returns, `main()` finds that `ptr` is pointing to a valid address and writes data inside the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

C function arguments are passed by value. This means that when you pass `ptr` to `allocateMem` and then modify it within `allocateMem`, you're not changing anything about `ptr`.

You *are* creating a memory leak, since you can't free the memory you've dynamically allocated as you haven't preserved a pointer to it.

Any argument you want a function to modify external to the function you're calling, you need to pass a pointer to, so if you want to modify a pointer, you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, as @babon has demonstrated with the code in their answer.

Comment: "_when you pass `ptr` to `allocateMem` and then modify it within..._" -- To put a finer point on this, `a` is a _copy_ of `ptr`, and it is `a` which is modified, not `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the pointer to the allocated memory (and check the return value), like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *allocateMem(void)
{
    return (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    if( NULL != (ptr = allocateMem()))
    {
        ptr[0] = 5454;
        ptr[1] = 54;
        printf("Hi %d\n", ptr[1]);
        free(ptr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The constant number `5` in allocateMem should not be hardcoded, or give it a valuable name.